# Why performance of Illustrator CS6 slower than Illustrator CS5.1?

Tags: vb.net, adobe-illustrator

Ex: Process get text of TextFrame has 657 characters:

```
 Dim t1 As String
  Dim t2 As String
  t1 = DateTime.Now.Minute & " " & DateTime.Now.Second & " " & DateTime.Now.Millisecond
  Dim text As String
  For iChar = 1 To iCharNum
      oChar = oContents.Characters(iChar)
      Dim str As String
      str = oChar.contents.ToString
      text = text & str
  Next
  t2 = DateTime.Now.Minute & " " & DateTime.Now.Second & " " & DateTime.Now.Millisecond
```

Result:

```
Time of CS5.1: 0s 487
           t1= 38 43 71
           t2= 38 43 558
Time of CS6: 3s 871
           t1=42 54 738
           t2=42 58 609
```

Why performance of Illustrator CS6 slower than Illustrator CS5.1?

Can I set attribute increase performance of Illustrator CS6?

Download Program and data test at here https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsszn3qh76q6u70/Test.rar?dl=0

Comment: An isolated test on a single computer isn't exactly a reliable benchmark.

Comment: I test on 6 computers.

Comment: Then why are we only seeing results for one?

Comment: that only a ex result, you can know performance of cs6 and cs5.

Comment: you can download program and data test at here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsszn3qh76q6u70/Test.rar?dl=0

Comment: You're basing your conclusion ("CS6 is slower than CS 5.1" on a single test running from Excel macro's. I hardly think that's a fair comparison and suggest you just accept it as a given that this particular usage has slowed down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have CS6 yet, however I have few ideas:

1. You may have diffrent configurations in these two versions.

   Diffrent rendering mode may be used, more GPU enchancements may be turned on by default in new version.

   However compare settings in these two versions.
2. My Nvidia Quadro graphics card can use **diffrent settings for applications**. Please go to your Windows display settings and see if there are some profiles/settings for diffrent games or applications. Maybe you have diffrent display settings for these two versions. I saw this feature also in GeForce and Ati FireGL.
3. Check your plugins. Maybe some plugin is slowing down CS6.

Comment: You are right, there is no such thing like performance settings in AI. I edited my post, removed wrong information and added 2 other suggestions.